# how to deactivate all associated records after deactivating parent record in php

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a job portal where i have one organization that is employer.
Organization has many users.
it's user can upload multiple jobs that is:-
user has many postedJobs
and so on ..

Just want to ask what logic should I write so that if I deactivate organization's account from Admin panel all of it's related records that is users, posted jobs,etc etc would also be deactivated automatically and should not be accessible from the homepage of website.

Or if I deactivate any of it's user then only all the records associated with that user will be deactivated and should not be accessible from the homepage of the website.

Comment: you could soft delete your user

Answer (score 0):

You can add "organization_id, user_id, visibility" columns to posts, jobs etc. tables. When you disable the organization or user, you can filter post and job records according to "organization_id, user_id" columns, and you can make these records "visibility=false"